# Multiple arguments transition mixin

Tags: css, stylus

I just want to implement a basic mixin for the transitions, this is my code:

```
transition()
    transition         arguments
    -webkit-transition arguments
```

Until i use this mixin with a single property all is working fine, but when i try to do something like this:

```
a
   transition(color 1s, text-shadow 1s)
```

My output is:

```
a {
    transition: color 1s text-shadow 1s;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s text-shadow 1s;   
}
```

no commas are added... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue auto-solved simply by removing the parentheses:

```
a
    transition color 1s, text-shadow 1s
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
trans = color 1s, text-shadow 1s

a
    transition(trans)
```

My output for this is:

```
a {
  transition: color 1s, text-shadow 1s;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s, text-shadow 1s;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works too, but I feel mine a bit more clean, +1!

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r 's solution is really the correct one, but in my case it didn't work (think something odd is happening on my site).This solution solved it for me, thanks Alexey

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple transition @mixin that accepts two arguments.

```
@mixin transition($arg1, $arg2) {
  -webkit-transition: $arg1, $arg2;
  -moz-transition:    $arg1, $arg2;
  -ms-transition:     $arg1, $arg2;
  -o-transition:      $arg1, $arg2;
  transition:         $arg1, $arg2;
}
```

Your declaration block would be:

```
@include transition(background .3s, color .3s);
```

CSS output:

```
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
```

Anymore than two arguments, I suggest refactoring the @mixin with a function.